# Least Squares Question to show proportion

Tags: least-squares, binary-data, proportion

I have a question.
Let's say data has been collected for people with jobs and people without jobs.
People with Jobs are represented by 1, people without jobs are represented by 0.

How do you use a least square method to show the proportion of people with jobs or the proportion of people without jobs?

Comment: Descriptive statistics do not need a least square method/linear regression line -they're just descriptive. Just think: what would the "squared deviations" be in the case you describe, so that _least_ squares would come in and minimize? You just have two bars adding up to unity, a pie split in two possibly unequal pieces... that's all.

Comment: You only appear to have one variable (itself 0-1); all the information about it is in the two counts (number with jobs, number without). You wouldn't use regression on a single variable.

Comment: Would the "squared deviations" be the difference between the total number of people and the people with jobs?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to see if other variables in your data are related to the probability of someone having a job?

Comment: I think this is an "interview question"- trying to ask whether people understand that if the dependent variable is a characteristic function, then least squares gives you the conditional expectation of the characteristic function, ie the probability, $E(\chi(\text{person with job})|x)=p(\text{person has job}|x)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_i$ be the dummy variable which describes the job status (0 or 1). Then run the next regression:

$$d_i=\alpha+u_i$$

In this case $\hat\alpha$ is the estimator of the desired proportion...

Comment: What is the $u_i$ term?